# MySQL - Search for column value based on another column value

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have the following SQL statement to calculate several fields based on 3 Wordpress tables. What I need is to calculate the `SUM` and `AVG` which are not working in the statement below.

I need to sum all meta_values '3279' only when `meta_key = image`. The same applies to the `AVG` formula, ie, avg all meta_values when `meta_key=odd`.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
SELECT (user_nicename) AS user,
       SELECT SUM(IF('meta_key' = 'image', 'meta_value' = '3279', 1,0)) AS won,
       SELECT SUM(IF('meta_key' = 'image', 'meta_value' = '3280', 1,0)) AS lost,
       COUNT('meta_key'='odd') AS total,
       FORMAT (AVG('meta_key' = 'odd', 'meta_value'),1) AS 'average odd',
       FORMAT (AVG ('meta_key' = 'bet', 'meta_value'),1) AS 'average bet',
       SUM('meta_key' = 'roi', 'meta_value') AS ROI
FROM wp_postmeta pm, wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON pm.post_id = p.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_users u ON p.post_author = u.ID
WHERE Month(data) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY (user_nicename)
ORDER BY ROI DESC
```

Comment: change the 1 to null in the avg statements. Nulls aren't counted in aggregates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be ways to simplify this in mysql. You might need to cast meta_value depending on what type it is, but to average on a subset of data, use null to ignore:

```
AVG(Case When meta_key = 'odd' Then meta_value else Null End)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exacly what I needed.